# Spring-Kafka: BATCH mode + Async commit. How to recover from kafka broker failures?

Tags: asynchronous, spring-kafka

**Tech:**

- spring-kafka 2.2.7
- enable.auto.commit = false
- AckMode.BATCH
- isSyncCommits = false
- number of partitions: 24
- number of consumers: 12 (concurrency in Spring terms)

**Issue Scenario:**
Couple kafka cluster nodes went  down and kafka broker started reporting exceptions instead of accepting our commits. Default async callback was just printing those errors out to the logs.
Polling continued. Messages were processing just fine (but none committed).
After 10 minutes the prod support spotted errors in logs. The kafka cluster was restored, the suffering process was bounced.
Since commits were dropped by broker for some time the process got around 2 millions duplicate messages to deal with.

**Questions:**

- We can keep the latest successful offset per TopicPartition in the concurrent map. So in the case the broker is broke again we could ensure the failed offset is higher than the latest successful one and **then ... do what**?
- Does Spring framework allow resending the failed commit anyhow from inside async callback ?
- Is there any way to resend failed commits synchronously from
  inside callback until the broker is back from outage ? (this should also block poll() since it's being call by the same thread I suspect)

(We would like to keep BATCH and Async because without them the entire thing can barely make it around 1000 messages a second which is slow)

I would be very grateful for advises/ideas!
Thank you !

P.S. Ideally we want it to self recover (we have the self-recovering in the scala + akka-streams based microservices so I know this works)

Answer (score 0):

2.2.x is no longer supported.

There are now several options for Batch error handlers.

`SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler` (Since 2.1 - ability to delay between retries added in 2.3) - Replays the entire batch indefinitely until successful.

`RetryingBatchErrorHandler` (since 2.3.7) - Pauses the consumer and retries (with back off); when retries are exhausted sends each record to a recoverer (such as the `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer`.

`RecoveringBatchErrorHandler` (since 2.5) - if the listener throws a `BatchListenerFailedException` (indicating which record in the batch failed), offsets for records before that record are committed and the rest are redelivered (until retries are exhausted when the failing record is sent to the recoverer). For all other exceptions, it falls back to the `SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler` with no back off.

However when using async commits, no exception is thrown so the error handler is not invoked.

It's best to make sure your replication factor is sufficient to be able to handle some number of brokers being down.

Comment: Thank you ! Very appreciate your work on spark kafka lib! I got it about ErrorHandlers. Those are useful for when the message processing failed and we need to "replay" it. Regarding async. Commits can fail due to some other issues. So still it would be great being able to resend failed commits. Maybe you know would it be possible to create an AsyncCommitCallback with Autowired kafkaConsumer in it ?(I tried, it didn't work but i hope there is some trick maybe :)) All we need is just the relevant consumer reference to invoke commitSync or commitAsync.

Comment: I have nothing to do with spark. The problem, here, is that the offsets for the next batch(es) may have already been committed (thus self-fixing the problem). Rolling back to the failed commits means you could end up reprocessing those batches, if the app is then restarted. It's a difficult problem to resolve.

Comment: sorry, typo (doing something with spark currently, this is why I guess). Spring Kafka of course! Thank you for responding. All is clear.